# C++ embedded python and environment variables

Tags: python, c++, environment-variables, python-c-api

I have create a C++ application that use python using the python C++ library and I have temporarily change my PATH variable into C++ using this code

```
GetEnvironmentVariable( _T("PATH"), szSysPath.GetBuffer(32000), 32000) ;
szSysPath.ReleaseBuffer() ;

szSysPath = _T("C:\\Path1;") +
            _T("C:\\Path2;") +
            szSysPath ;

SetEnvironmentVariable( _T("PATH"), szSysPath );
```

Next, I have initialized Python using

```
Py_Initialize() ;
```

This code is OK because I can execute many script Python using my application but when I execute a script that show the PATH, my new paths added are not present.

This is my Python script

```
import os

print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

Do you have any ideas about this problem? Maybe i must update library os with new data?
Thanks

Comment: That `_T` is a really bad idea here. It's hiding some Windows95/Windows NT differences in character set, but that is critically important here. Practically speaking, there are two environments: ANSI and Unicode, and they're kept roughly in sync. So we don't know what the code above is really doing.

Comment: ANSI and Unicode are not the problem. The problem is that I set the PATH variable in C++ but into Python this change is not reflected and i see old status of PATH variable

Comment: the fact that you talk about **the** `PATH` variable is already indicative. Effectively, there are two.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I solved using a direct call of Python functions. 

    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString( pEnviron, "_ _ setitem _ _" );

    GetEnvironmentVariable( _T("PATH"), szSysPath.GetBuffer(32000), 32000) ;
    szSysPath.ReleaseBuffer() ;

    pArgs = Py_BuildValue( "(uu)", _T("PATH"), szSysPath );
    PyObject_CallObject( pFunc, pArgs );
    Py_DECREF( pArgs );